# Scantokens and balanced text, what options exist for curly braces?

Tags: expansion, braces, scantokens

`\scantokens` takes balanced text as its argument, and braces have to be explicit, as far as I can tell.  I'm puzzled by the following, where the first line is okay and the second line results in a "file ended..." error.  Why?

```
\toks0=\scantokens{{abc}}            
\toks0=\expandafter{\scantokens{abc}}
```

I believe `\scantokens` is expandable, as I've used it inside an `\edef`.  In that context, it normally has to be preceded with `\endlinechar-1 \everyeof{\noexpand}`.

I'm guessing the use of `\expandafter` is producing some kind of file write/read state that requires similar use of `\endlinechar` and `\noexpand`.  But then it seems like both of the above two lines should result in the same error.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the first form `\scantokens` completes first leaving `{abc}` as the balanced text but the second form the `{` is interleaved and the implicit end of file marker is seen while the balanced text of the token asssignment is being scanned.

This feature of `\scantokens` is almost totally unhelpful luatex provides `\scantextokens` which is the same but without the eof error.

```
\toks0=\scantextokens{{abc}}            
\toks0=\expandafter{\scantextokens{abc}}
```

Comment: I can use the double-brace form, so it's not really an issue.  However, I prefer the second form with the \expandafter, because it's more consistent with other token assignments.  Also, it's weird to have the braces for \toks0 inside what's being re-scanned.

Thanks for the suggestion about luatex.  I haven't made the switch yet, but it does seem worthwhile.

Comment: For anyone who's interested, I tried to silence the end of file marker that David mentions with `\everyeof{\noexpand}` but it didn't help.  The only way to get the token assignment seems to be the following.  If anyone knows of an alternative, kindly share the technique with me.
```\endlinechar-1 \everyeof{\noexpand}
\edef\next{\toks0={\scantokens{abc}}}
\next```

Comment: @DanLevin why don't you simply use `\scantokens{\toks0={abc}}`  which doesn't require any eof tricks?

Comment: I will sheepishly (?) admit I'm doing some funny business with catcodes.  I'm trying to get a string with ordinary brace characters.  I didn't want to complicate the question above.  But since you asked, it comes down to using special characters as delimiters (given catcodes 1 and 2), and making braces ordinary characters inside `\scantokens`, something like `\scantokens^^A{...}^^B`.  I'm stymied.

Comment: `\begingroup
\everyeof{\noexpand}
\catcode\`\^^A=1
\catcode\`\^^B=2
\catcode\`\{=12
\catcode\`\}=12
\xdef\foo^^A\scantokens^^A{...}^^B^^B
\endgroup
\tt \foo
\bye`  ? @DanLevin